# From cumulants of a random variable to its moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, recurrence-relations, moment-problem

This question is very related to:

> [Infinite sum of Gamma random variables with same shape parameter but different rate parameter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812238/infinite-sum-of-gamma-random-variables-with-same-shape-parameter-but-different-r)

In particular I know that a random variable $Q_n'$ has $j$-th cumulant given by:
$$
\kappa_j'^{(n)} = \frac{1}{2}(j-1)!\frac{2^{jn}-1}{2^{j}-1}
$$
In general we can express the $k$-th moment $\mu_k'^{(n)} = \mathbb{E}(Q_n'^k)$ in terms of the previous cumulants $(\kappa_1,\dots,\kappa_k)$ using the incomplete Bell polynomials as pointed out here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant

I would like to express the $k$-th moment $\mu_k^{(n)} = \mathbb{E}(Q_n^k)$ in terms of $k$ and $n$. Using the following code in Mathematica:

```
e[k_, n_] := 
 Replace[MomentConvert[Moment[k], "Cumulant"], 
  Cumulant[j_] :> 1/2*Factorial[j - 1]*((2^(j*n) - 1)/(2^j - 1)), All]
```

it's possible to generate $\mu_k'^{(n)}$, for example if we fix $n$ and we table the first values for $k$ we obtain:

[image: First moments]

I'm sure there is some kind of first step recurrence between $\mu_{k}^{(n)}$ but it's very difficult to see the right way of proceeding.

**BACKGROUND OF THE QUESTION**

Because of the question I've already mentioned above, I manage to find a work written by James Pachares which propose a method to compute the CDF of the sum of $n$ weighted chi-square variables:

> https://www.jstor.org/stable/2236764

In particular he defines $Q_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_iX_i$ as the sum of $n$ weighted chi-square variables with 1 degrees of freedom ($X_i\sim\chi_{(1)}^2$ i.i.d.), for which he proved the following theorem:
$$
F_n(1) = P(Q_n \leq 1) =  \Bigl(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\Bigr)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{\mathbb{E}(Q_n'^{k})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}n+k+1)}
$$

where $Q_n'^{k} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (a_i)^{-1} X_i$.

In my case $a_i = \frac{1}{2^{i-1}}$ , $\forall i\geq 1$ and $\kappa_j'^{(n)}$ are the cumulants of $Q_n'^{k}$ which I have defined above, and in particular I would like to determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(1)$.

In order to use this theorem to compute this probability it's necessary to know the $k$-th moment of $Q_n'$.. I don't really know how to find a "better looking" expression for $\mu_{k}'^{(n)}$ and so I'm asking if you have some ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: See Chapter 3 of Kendall's *The Advanced Theory of Statistics, Vol I*.